# MinionPro lining figures for euler math

Tags: fonts, eulervm, minionpro

Using MinionPro and Euler looks great, except the euler digits are too large.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[onlytext,footnotefigures]{MinionPro}
\usepackage[T1,small,euler-digits]{eulervm}
\begin{document}
old 123 and math $123$
\begin{align}
123 \sum_{i=1}^{n} x^{i}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

compared with the original MinionPro figures

```
%\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[footnotefigures,mathlf]{MinionPro}
%\usepackage[T1,small,euler-digits]{eulervm}
```

[image]

If Idisable `euler-digits`

```
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[onlytext,footnotefigures]{MinionPro}
\usepackage[T1,small]{eulervm}
```

I get everything in old style

[image]

I would like to have the last example with MinionPro lining figures in math mode. Is this possible (in pdflatex)?

Comment: can't prove this, because I don't have MinionPro installed, so my guess is to load MinionPro after eulervm. but it's speculation at best.

Comment: Solved! Make it an answer and I check it. However I could swear I tried this first without an effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer as requested by QO (solution is untested, because I don't have MinionPro):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\usepackage[T1,small]{eulervm}
\usepackage[onlytext,footnotefigures]{MinionPro}

\begin{document}
old 123 and math $123$
\begin{align}
123 \sum_{i=1}^{n} x^{i}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

A simple reorder of `eulervm` and `MinionPro` should provide the necessary effect.

Comment: You have to remove `euler-digits` from `eulervm`. I edited your answer, but it needs peer review.